# html5Mode gives errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to remove the # in my URL to clean it. I did what everyone tells to do:

```
demoApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 

        // Système de routage
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/contact/:msg?', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactCtrl'
        })
        .when('/todolist', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/todolist.html',
            controller: 'listeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/testfiltre', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/testfiltre.html',
            controller: 'demoFiltreCtrl'
        })
        .when('/testCreationfiltre', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/testcreationfiltre.html',
            controller: 'demoCreationFiltreCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

HTML file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo App</title>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.2/angular-locale_fr-ca.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

It gives me a bunch of errors when I do that and I really lokked around and didn't find the solution. My url becomes like this for some reason:

```
file:///C:/Users/......../index.html#%252525252525252525252Fhome
```

insted of

```
file:///C:/Users/......../index.html/home
```

It gives errors like:

> Error: The operation is insecure.
>
> Error: Access to restricted URI denied
>
> Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: pages/home.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$compile/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
>
> Error: The operation is insecure.
>
> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>
> Error: The operation is insecure.

....

Comment: Basically `file` protocol doesn't supported in ajax..in short your code must be hosted on server..so that while access template via Ajax would be accessible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a good article that describe how to remove # from URL

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1063634/Removing-the-sharp-Sign-from-AngularJS-URLs-with-I

Comment: you need to do step 2 . in order to solve the not found error

Comment: I'm testing my application just by dragging and dropping the index.html in the browser by the way

Comment: **first** you need to remove if statement **if(window.history && window.history.pushState)**,
**second** you need hosting Like **IIS** to route your files
**third** you need to add otherwise option in routing configuration

Comment: I'm gonna try on my real server, but is there a way to make it work on the localhost? How can I have IIS on my localhost?

Comment: Search on Turn Windows Feature On or Off, Then Select all check boxes of Internet Information Services. this will install IIS.

Comment: I did what you said, but it still doesn't work. I get this error: GET http://localhost:8080/pages/home.html  . The problem is that the path should be: http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/pages/home.html

Comment: so you will need to adjust the path in routing configuration

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that I noticed us that you forgive about `otherwise` statement. Also it's strange that your views are tried to be loaded with `file` protocol.

As a suggestion: think about using `ui-router` instead of `ng-route` because its has better functionality, great support for nested views (your views' tree can be as deeper as you need) and named views and its not as so buggy as `ng-route`

Comment: Actually, I have the otherwise statement. I just diodn't write it in my post cause I tought it wouldn't be necessary. I'm not using ui-router now, because I'm still learning Angular JS and I want to understand as most as possible angular JS before using ui-router.

Comment: Well, why do you check `window.history` object before setting up `html5mode`? All your application settings are taking place at a startup. Are you sure this object exists at this time? Your `if` statement can results in false always and this is possibly not to turned on the `html5mode`

Comment: Someone suggested ot, but it still does the same thing if I remove the if

Comment: I tried on my web server (I use webfaction), but it still doesn't work. It work if I go at home (because of otherwise), but I can't change page (this is the link to my app: http://kevdug.webfactional.com)

Comment: Do you have a state which is configured as a home state? Because you need to configure state for your otherwise condition (mostly for `/` url)

Comment: I'm not sur eif I understand your question but I have the otherwise condition set at home

Comment: Ok, so why your base url is configured to `/` then?

Comment: because that's what the site I checked told me to do. I'm updating my question.